# 2D bouncing formula doesn't work properly

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, raycasting

I am new to Unity, and I am trying to create a bouncing ball, so I've been researching bouncing related physics and I found a formula:

Formula:

```
-2*(V dot N)*N + V
```

Where V is the velocity vector and N is the normal of the surface on which the ball will bounce

Here is my script :

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class BallPhysics : MonoBehaviour {



    void Start () {
        rigidbody2D.velocity =new Vector2 (-1,-3);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Pong") {
            tBounce ();
                }


    }

    void tBounce(){
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (new Vector2 (transform.position.x,transform.position.y), rigidbody2D.velocity);
        Vector2 n = hit.normal;
        Vector2 v = rigidbody2D.velocity;
        Vector2 R = -2 * (Vector2.Dot (v, n)) * n + v;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = R;
    }
}
```

I am giving the ball a velocity vector in the start function, i am using OnTriggerEnter2D for collision handling and raycast2D to get the normal of a surface.

The problem is that the script doesn't reflect the velocity vector called R, I think the problem is in the normal vector.

For example let's say V is a Vector2(-1,-1) so basically R should be (-1,1), but it's not. R is (3,1) !

I've successfully been able to make a ball bouncing on Horizontal/vertical surface by reversing the ball velocity but this won't work properly with arbitrary angles, that's why I am using this formula.
So what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

normalize your normal vector `n` before using in in the reflect formula.

```
Vector2 n = hit.normal;
n.Normalize();
```